# VBA Ribbon UI What is the name of the Word image

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbon

Microsoft Word 2010

[image: Microsoft Word]

I am trying to find the imageMso for Word inside of Word 2010. Word has all the other Office products icons listed in WordControls.xlsx, but apparently not itself. I need it for a group image in my Word ribbon tab.

For the moment, I grabbed a copy of the one displayed in explorer.

Comment: The first button in the standard VBE toolbar is the host application's icon. It's old, 16x16 and ugly though. In Excel that's FaceId 106; I bet the FaceId for Word's icon would be 107, or something close to it... but you're probably much better off with the (much nicer-looking) icon you're using now.

Comment: Actually, the VBE host icon doesn't necessarily match the actual host icon. For example, Outlook's VBE uses an Outlook 2000-style 16x16 icon, but Outlook 2016 itself uses the 2016 icon.

Answer (score 0):

CustomUI does provide images for most of the other Office applications, and even includes an icon for FoxPro, but it doesn't include images for Word or Visio.

And, no amount of poking around for an undocumented imageMso seems to work...

[image]

Subject to licence terms, you could try the new [Fabric icons](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/styles/brand-icons) provided by Microsoft, but you'd have to embed the images and do your own image replacement if you wanted to reflect the right icon version for each version of Word.

Comment: I'll stick with my current image as it best represents the group of Word functions I've added to the tab for the user's convenience. It just seemed odd that Microsoft Word did not include an imageMSO of itself for convenience at the very least.